# FFMPEG: Sony IPCM 24bit four channel Audio and Final Cut Pro x from Sony A7S III or FX3

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video, batch, transcode

I just got a new camera that uses IPCM Files for four channel audio 24 bit tracks in the video. Is there a way to BATCH-rewrap those files so that they are readable in Final cut for example.
There has been a discussion here:
http://forum.doom9.net/showthread.php?p=1942423
But I dont know how to batch process files with ffmpeg.
Ffworks for mac can batch-process files for example but doesnt seem to be able to read the audio in the video file..

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: FCP is supposed to natively support the a7S III and ILME-FX3